# Why didn't Ollivander make the obvious choice of testing the twin core wand on Harry earlier?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

In the first book, while Ollivander is trying to find a suitable wand for Harry, it seems it was a difficult process at first, as Ollivander does not seem to be happy with most of his first choices.

> Harry tried and tried. He had no idea what Mr Ollivander was waiting
> for. The pile of tried wands was mounting higher and higher on the
> spindly chair, but the more wands Mr Ollivander pulled from the
> shelves, the happier he seemed to become.

It says there was a pile of tried wands that he wasn't satisfied with, and apparently the more wands he found to be unsatisfactory, the happier he became. But instead of just piling wands upon wands, why didn't he make the obvious choice of trying the twin core wand, once a couple had not worked? He knew what Harry's relationship to Voldemort was, and he knew he had a wand that was a twin of the one that gave Harry the scar. Moreover, as soon as he lets Harry try out the twin core wand, he seems to be immediately satisfied.

Is it explained, or can it somehow be inferred, why he didn't make the obvious choice, and tried the twin core one once just a few wands had proved unsatisfactory? Does this question have a more interesting answer than wizards not having logical skills?

Comment: How is it obvious though? I mean, as a reader, I can understand that it's a book plot. But as someone who's living his daily life?

Comment: @Clockwork The book says that as the wands pile up, Ollivander seems happier, and I am sure he knows/remembers he has the twin of the wand that attacked Harry. So in universe it seems to be one of the first choices he could have made once few of the wands he tried were unsatisfactory.

Comment: If anything, it seems like it would be obviously NOT that one, from what we knew at this point in the story.

Comment: @user13267: It's arguable that Olivander being happier is about the fact that Harry seems to be a special case; if, as a software developer, you're trying to figure out how to fix a particular bug - and the simple, *obvious* fixes don't seem to work, that means you're working on a bug that,to some, would be *interesting* to devote time to try and fix.Or perhaps like being an IT technician realizing they're getting further and further away from "Have you tried turning it off and on again? Have you checked if it's plugged in?" script;You may not know where the endpoint is,but you know it's more.

Comment: It feels like testing the twin core wand IS the "Have you tried turning it off and on again" moment in this situation, rather than trying to find out that one rough program in Taskmanager that is not letting you delete that folder (equivalent to piling up unsatisfactory wands)

Answer (score 7):

**Ollivander Likely Thought it was Counterintuitive for the Holly Wand to Choose Harry**

So I'll caveat this with "there is no accepted canonical reason because JKR hasn't said anything and we never get a "look" into Ollivander's mind on the subject."  But given that "The wand chooses the wizard" it would have been counterintuitive to Ollivander that the Holly twin core would choose Harry.  Ollivander believes that wands can know/sense things about people that aren't readily apparent, and we know that to be true.  For example in *Deathly Hallows* Harry is the master of the Elder Wand because he disarmed Draco Malfoy "weeks ago".  For that to be true the Elder Wand has to know Draco won it from Dumbledore despite never touching Draco, AND that Harry disarmed Draco even though the Elder Wand wasn't even around!

Ollivander says in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* that it is "Curious" the Holly wand chooses Harry because "It's brother gave you that scar."  This implies that Ollivander believes/suspects the Holly wand knows it's twin attacked Harry with the intent to kill or was otherwise opposed to Harry.  As Ollivander considers the wands brothers it's not unreasonable to believe Ollivander didn't test the Holly wand on Harry sooner because *obviously* it would not choose a wizard that it's twin was in conflict with.